# Simple rigging problem (or not simple at all)!

Tags: rigging, armature, inverse-kinematics

I have a problem that seemed simple to me, but whatever I've tried that turned not to be that simple.

I have 2 opposite L shapes with fixed rotation center. Their ends are connected with lever. At both ends I have two empties where first empty (Ctrl_A) affects movement of another one (Ctrl B). I'm interested only in Z location of both empties where their Z location is same as Z location of the center of the closest white circle of L shape.

[image]

So, in simple terms, I have to move Control empty A up or down and get a resulting position of control empty B like it's shown on image above.

I've tried for several hours with armature, track-to constraints, drivers, etc... and quit because I couldn't manage to get anything in place to achieve desirable result.

I'm not looking for quick complete solution, just a proper way how to make it work. I almost know nothing how armature works and all these settings are so confusing to me.

Comment: Am thinking that I might use an Armature with bone poses to accomplish this...

Comment: @james_t, That will work for sure but there's a lot of manual job. I have to control everything by just moving empty controller A up and down. I've just simplified my question, solution is part of much complex problem.

Comment: Hi. Please use a title that matches the content of the question. It should be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the issue so that anyone searching for a similar problem is likely to find it. Remove anything superfluous, avoid using words like "*this*", "*help with*", "*issue*" or "*question about*", instead describe what "it" is. Remember, your title is the first thing potential visitors see, answers you get depend heavily on how insightful it is. See [*What is the problem of asking “How do I do this?"*](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So since A and B are interdependent, you can't control from both of them-- you need to pick one or the other to control.  We'll control from A.  This will determine the position of B.

[image]

"Track" tracks "A", however you'd like (I'm using a damped track, but you may prefer a locked track.)  A 2-bone IK chain inherits starting position and rotation from this tracking, reaching to the static (relative to root) Rot B.  B, our output, merely inherits the rotation of the last part of the IK chain (ik2).

Shown with a couple poses, with some simple meshes:

[image]

You may wish to lock the IK the prevent rotation in undesired axes-- as shown, past a certain point, ik1 will rotate 180 degrees about Y to maintain its bend.  But maybe you're not even rotating it that far (as shown, the lever is too long to rotate that far without discontinuity.)

B gives us the white circle (since it's not really a control.)  To get A's white circle, we can just take the position of the tail of track.  If you'd rather, you can parent a bone to Track at the location of its tail and measure the position of that bone-- a million ways to do it, just depends on what's most convenient for your purposes.

Comment: English is not my native so I might be confusing... And yes, I have to control only **Ctrl A**, Ctrl B is actually not a controller, it's a result. Anyway, this looks like what I need. Give me some time to try to figure out how this works.

Comment: if I understood this well... There's one armature at left L profile to control its movement and rotation with IK bone. Next armature is parented to lever and right L shape where the biggest bone is parented to lever and used to push IK bone at L profile. I don't understand what is root bone? is it just parent to them all or has another purpose here?

Comment: I put a root bone in all armatures.  Yes, it's just the parent to everything, to be able to control the space the structure exists in.

Comment: Thanx a million. This is exactly what I was looking for.